# Does recvfrom() on an IPv6 socket always return an IPv6 address in 'from' parameter?

Tags: sockets, udp

Does [`recvfrom()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock/nf-winsock-recvfrom) on an IPv6 socket always return an IPv6 address in the `from` parameter? My concern is if an IPv6 socket communicates with an IPv4 target by IPv4 mapped IPv6 address, is it possible  that `recvfrom()` returns an IPv4 address directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An `AF_INET` (IPv4) socket only works with IPv4 addresses.

An `AF_INET6` (IPv6) socket only works with IPv6 addresses.

A [dual-stack socket](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/dual-stack-sockets) is an `AF_INET6` socket with the `IPV6_V6ONLY` option turned off so it can work with both IPv4 and IPv6 peers. Since it is an IPv6 socket, IPv4 addresses will always be represented as IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses.  This is clearly stated in the documentation:

> IP Addresses with a Dual-Stack Socket
>
> **Dual-stack sockets always require IPv6 addresses. The ability to interact with an IPv4 address requires the use of the IPv4-mapped IPv6 address format. Any IPv4 addresses must be represented in the IPv4-mapped IPv6 address format which enables an IPv6 only application to communicate with an IPv4 node. The IPv4-mapped IPv6 address format allows the IPv4 address of an IPv4 node to be represented as an IPv6 address.** The IPv4 address is encoded into the low-order 32 bits of the IPv6 address, and the high-order 96 bits hold the fixed prefix 0:0:0:0:0:FFFF. The IPv4-mapped IPv6 address format is specified in RFC 4291. For more information, see [www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4291.txt](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4291.txt). The IN6ADDR_SETV4MAPPED macro in Mstcpip.h can be used to convert an IPv4 address to the required IPv4-mapped IPv6 address format.
>
> **If the underlying protocol is actually IPv4, then the IPv4 address is mapped into an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address format. That is the, family field in the SOCKADDR structure indicates AF_INET6, but an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address is encoded in the IPv6 address structure. For a dual-stack socket in listening mode, this means that any accepted IPv4 connections will return an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address.** For a dual-stack socket that is connecting to an IPv4 destination, the SOCKADDR structure passed to connect must be an IPv4-mapped IPv6 address. Applications must take care to handle these IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses appropriately and only use them with dual stack sockets. If an IP address is to be passed to a regular IPv4 socket, the address must be a regular IPv4 address not a IPv4-mapped IPv6 address.